# Building an Android button with pictures and text

Tags: android, android-widget

I am looking to build a button in my Android app which must contain:

- A background picture
- A picture
- Some text

I am coming from iPhone dev and I am a little bit confused by Android development.
While I could `addSubView:` UIImageView or UILabel to my UIButton, I can't use `addView()` with a android.widget.Button :(

Does anyone have a solution?

**EDIT :** Thanks everybody for answers. I forgot to specify I have to do it programmatically, without using XML. I don't know how many element I will display (it depends on RSS).

Comment: Here is what I already did in my iPhone app : http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/8240/advancedbutton.png. That's a simple UIButton, composed of a UILabel and a UIImage, with a background image.

Comment: looks like a ListView item  .... check this sample http://esilo.pl/LooserSample.zip (note: it was a sample for other guy, so dont take "Looser" for yourself :) )

Comment: Ok. Looks like a ListView is what i was looking for. If you want you can create a new answer which I will validate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:background` for background ... remeber that you can build your own [9 patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html)

`android:drawableLeft`, `android:drawableRight`, `android:drawableTop`, `android:drawableBottom` to add some picture to the left, right, ... of text

EDIT: i didn't mention ... but i was talking about android.widget.Button

2nd EDIT: after you provide more information i think that all what you need is ListView

check this sample http://esilo.pl/LooserSample.zip (don't take "looser" to yourself, it was sample for another guy)

it showing how to

1. download a JSON data
2. store it in db
3. build ContentProvider for sharing a data
4. use ContentProvider to take data from db and show it in ListView
5. dynamic loading images from internet

for simpler sample use your sdk samples like this C:\android\android-sdk-windows\samples\android-8\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\view\List*.java

if you alrady have code for downloading and storing data from RSS in array extend ArrayAdapter to fit your needs

Comment: Please take a look at my EDIT ;)

Answer (score 0):

Most, if not all, of the UI for android is built in the XML.  Kind of like the UI builder in Xcode, but not near as advanced.  The ADP will let you view the UI you have built in Eclipse, and adjust some basic widget properties.

I believe for what you are trying to do, if I understand right, you need to use an ImageButton widget.  This widget allows you to use a complete image as a button.  You can also define your own states (button pressed, gain focus, etc) with both the button and image button widgets.  You can define a background and add images to both widgets.

More information [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)